# How to get horizontal output when parsing json file to csv file in python

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing

I want to convert my json file to csv file using python. I wrote a script for that but script not working correctly. My json template looks like

```
{
 "-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr" : {
"key1" : 0,
"key2" : false,
"key3" : 0,
"key4" : 0,
"key5" : "01/01/2016 04:04",
"key" : "-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr",
"key6" : "01/01/2016 04:04",
"key7" : 23,
"key8" : 0,
"key9" : {
  "date" : 1,
  "day" : 5,
  "hours" : 4,
  "minutes" : 4,
  "month" : 0,
  "seconds" : 56,
  "time" : 1451617496647,
  "timezoneOffset" : -60,
  "year" : 116
},
"triedConnector" : {
  "OPENSL" : -1,
  "SAPA" : -1,
  "USB" : -1,
  "USB_7" : -1
},......
```

My Script (V3.x):

```
import json,csv,sys
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

fileInput = sys.argv[1] 
fileOutput = sys.argv[2]

inputFile = open(fileInput,'r') #open json file
outputFile = open(fileOutput, 'w+') #load csv file

data = json.load(inputFile) #load json content

inputFile.close() #close the input file

csv_file = csv.writer(outputFile)

csv_file.writerow(["header 0", "header 1", "header 2", "header 3", "header 4"]) #headers

for value in data.values():
  for v in value.values():
    csv_file.writerow([unicode(v).encode('utf-8')])


for value in data.values():
  for v in value.values():
    for z in v.values():
        csv_file.writerow([unicode(z).encode('utf-8')])

outputFile.close()#close the output file
```

In this script first for loop should print like

```
-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr
-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr
-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr
```

and it's working perfectly but unfortunately my second for loop giving this output to my csv file

```
-KjR-JvTm3BKVkYWoyTV
-Kj5ZdfgX8lLLi-htqPU
-KkC4t0XQoJDViNqt18n

False

"{u'seconds': 18, u'year': 117, u'month': 4, u'hours': 8, u'time': 1494223818226L, u'date': 8, u'minutes': 10, u'day': 1, u'timezoneOffset': -120}"

0
08/05/2017 08:10
"{u'OPENSL': -1, u'USB_7': -1, u'SAPA': -1, u'USB': -1}"
08/05/2017 08:10
-KjafVrmb_wuwb36xNq0
0
23
0
0
```

I want a horizontal output for this and also my third loop for nested objects but and when I try to run my script for last loop I got this error:

> AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'values'.

Shortly my problem is I need a horizontal output like this

> K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr 0, false, 0, 0, 01/01/2016 04:04, -K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr
>   K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr 0, false, 0, 0, 01/01/2016 04:04, -K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr

So can anybody help me to understand and fix these issues please. Thank you

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: @BillBell Like this sir `K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr 0, false, 0, 0, 01/01/2016 04:04, -K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr 0, false, 0, 0, 01/01/2016 04:04, -K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code appears to do what you want except that the csv fields are in a different order. Normally that wouldn't matter. I've also attempted to make the code explain what it's doing.

The json is three copies of what you supplied in the question, slightly modified to compile properly, with the main key changed.

```
json_txt = '''\
{
"-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr" : {
    "key1" : 0, "key2" : false, "key3" : 0, "key4" : 0, "key5" : "01/01/2016 04:04",
    "key" : "-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr", "key6" : "01/01/2016 04:04", "key7" : 23,
    "key8" : 0,
    "key9" : { "date" : 1, "day" : 5, "hours" : 4, "minutes" : 4, "month" : 0,
        "seconds" : 56, "time" : 1451617496647, "timezoneOffset" : -60, "year" : 116},
    "triedConnector" : { "OPENSL" : -1, "SAPA" : -1, "USB" : -1, "USB_7" : -1}
    },
"-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_2" : {
    "key1" : 0, "key2" : false, "key3" : 0, "key4" : 0, "key5" : "01/01/2016 04:04",
    "key" : "-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr", "key6" : "01/01/2016 04:04", "key7" : 23,
    "key8" : 0,
    "key9" : { "date" : 1, "day" : 5, "hours" : 4, "minutes" : 4, "month" : 0,
        "seconds" : 56, "time" : 1451617496647, "timezoneOffset" : -60, "year" : 116},
    "triedConnector" : { "OPENSL" : -1, "SAPA" : -1, "USB" : -1, "USB_7" : -1}
    },
"-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_3" : {
    "key1" : 0, "key2" : false, "key3" : 0, "key4" : 0, "key5" : "01/01/2016 04:04",
    "key" : "-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr", "key6" : "01/01/2016 04:04", "key7" : 23,
    "key8" : 0,
    "key9" : { "date" : 1, "day" : 5, "hours" : 4, "minutes" : 4, "month" : 0,
        "seconds" : 56, "time" : 1451617496647, "timezoneOffset" : -60, "year" : 116},
    "triedConnector" : { "OPENSL" : -1, "SAPA" : -1, "USB" : -1, "USB_7" : -1}
    }
}'''

import json
import csv

data = json.loads(json_txt)
print ('data keys -->', data.keys())
print ('one of these keys (arbitrary) -->', list(data.keys())[0])
print ('keys for one object in data -->', list(data[list(data.keys())[0]].keys()))
key9_fields = data[list(data.keys())[0]]['key9'].keys()
print ('keys in key9 -->', key9_fields)

print ('Now writing csv ...')

the_fieldnames = list(data[list(data.keys())[0]].keys())
# remove triedConnector and key9
the_fieldnames.remove('triedConnector')
the_fieldnames.remove('key9')
# add items from key9
the_fieldnames.extend(key9_fields)
print (the_fieldnames)

with open('tpbafk_csv.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=the_fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for key in data.keys():
        row = {}
        for field_key in the_fieldnames:
            if field_key in key9_fields:
                row[field_key] = data[key]['key9'][field_key]
            else:
                row[field_key] = data[key][field_key]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Result as printed on stdout:

```
data keys --> dict_keys(['-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_2', '-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_3', '-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr'])
one of these keys (arbitrary) --> -K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_2
keys for one object in data --> ['key6', 'key8', 'triedConnector', 'key2', 'key7', 'key4', 'key', 'key5', 'key9', 'key3', 'key1']
keys in key9 --> dict_keys(['timezoneOffset', 'month', 'year', 'hours', 'time', 'day', 'seconds', 'date', 'minutes'])
Now writing csv ...
['key6', 'key8', 'key2', 'key7', 'key4', 'key', 'key5', 'key3', 'key1', 'timezoneOffset', 'month', 'year', 'hours', 'time', 'day', 'seconds', 'date', 'minutes']
```

csv file:

```
key6,key8,key2,key7,key4,key,key5,key3,key1,timezoneOffset,month,year,hours,time,day,seconds,date,minutes
01/01/2016 04:04,0,False,23,0,-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr,01/01/2016 04:04,0,0,-60,0,116,4,1451617496647,5,56,1,4
01/01/2016 04:04,0,False,23,0,-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr,01/01/2016 04:04,0,0,-60,0,116,4,1451617496647,5,56,1,4
01/01/2016 04:04,0,False,23,0,-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr,01/01/2016 04:04,0,0,-60,0,116,4,1451617496647,5,56,1,4
```

Comment: Sir this is worked very well. Thank you so much. Your are the BEST!! This is a very good and simple solution, Thank you so much again

Answer (score 0):

as said in the [csv.writer documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

> *If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with newline=''*

just fix this line:

```
outputFile = open(fileOutput, 'wb+', newline='') #load csv file
```

Comment: I tried but didn't work I got this error: TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: @tpbafk: any typo? [`newline` is definitely a keyword of open](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open)

Comment: @tpbafk: python version 2.x?

Comment: There is no argument for `open` method.I fixed it using `wb+`. Thank you anyway

Comment: @tpbafk: feel free to share your full solution or to close this question

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your json will be like this, so i wrote the script based  on below:

```
data = {
 "-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr" : {
"key1" : 0,
"key2" : False,
"key3" : 0,
"key4" : 0,
"key5" : "01/01/2016 04:04",
"key" : "-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr",
"key6" : "01/01/2016 04:04",
"key7" : 23,
"key8" : 0,
"key9" : {
  "date" : 1,
  "day" : 5,
  "hours" : 4,
  "minutes" : 4,
  "month" : 0,
  "seconds" : 56,
  "time" : 1451617496647,
  "timezoneOffset" : -60,
  "year" : 116
},
"triedConnector" : {
  "OPENSL" : -1,
  "SAPA" : -1,
  "USB" : -1,
  "USB_7" : -1
}}, "-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr1" : {
"key1" : 0,
"key2" : False,
"key3" : 0,
"key4" : 0,
"key5" : "01/01/2016 04:04",
"key" : "-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr",
"key6" : "01/01/2016 04:04",
"key7" : 23,
"key8" : 0,
"key9" : {
  "date" : 1,
  "day" : 5,
  "hours" : 4,
  "minutes" : 4,
  "month" : 0,
  "seconds" : 56,
  "time" : 1451617496647,
  "timezoneOffset" : -60,
  "year" : 116
},
"triedConnector" : {
  "OPENSL" : -1,
  "SAPA" : -1,
  "USB" : -1,
  "USB_7" : -1
}}}
```

code:

```
all_keys = ['key']
all_keys.extend('key%d' % i for i in range(1,6))
csv_data = [[data[val][key] for key in all_keys] for val in data.keys()]
import csv
with open('horizontal.csv','w+') as outfile:
    write = csv.writer(outfile)
    write.writerows(csv_data)
```

output:

```
-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr,False,0,0,01/01/2016 04:04
-K6v8Ht6nXCjaO_ApNGr,False,0,0,01/01/2016 04:04
```

Comment: I've already tried a slotiun like this before and It didn't worked. This is the almost same my old solution. The problem is:                       Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MuhammedMustafa\Desktop\Python27\test.py", line 32, in <module>
    csv_data = [[data[val][key] for key in all_keys] for val in data.keys()]
NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Comment: data = your_json_constraint else just try with my json data.

Comment: I tried with your json template and I got this error : "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded". I'm sorry but I'm new to python and It's syntax I've changed my code to [this](https://pastebin.com/pf3qzjsd) Could you check my code for error or somethig wrong ? But my I guess the interpreter can't read my json file because wrong format the full is error [here](https://pastebin.com/GJ8zhVLc)  my new [json is here](https://pastebin.com/VHQ5F7B5)

Comment: @tpbafk "connectorActivated" : false --> make this to False in  your json file before loading the json.

Comment: Nope didn't worked. I don't understand why so hard to convert a json file.